# RDiscount custom generated html

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, markdown

I'm using [RDiscount](https://github.com/rtomayko/rdiscount) to convert Markdown to html in my application. Actually when I add some code in my markdown it generates **code** and **pre** tags but I want to add a class to the **code** tag how can I do this ? I need to parse generated HTML with Nokogiri or something like this ?

Comment: Why do you want to add a CSS class to the <code> tag ? Can't you wrap the generated HTML in, say, a <div class="wrapper">, and apply CSS styles to its children ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rdiscount does not seem able to do this on its own. Parsing the result (with Nokogiri or whatever) might do the trick, but could be expensive. If you can, switch to another lib, like [Redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) for example. This one lookes like it can be extended quite easily to fit your needs

Comment: I can switch and I probably try Redcarpet :)

Answer (score 2):

One thing is sure, you can't tell Rdiscount to do it, it has no option for it. I looked at Rdiscount source code and this is what I end up in the file generate.c:

```c
static void
printcode(Line *t, MMIOT *f)
{
    int blanks;

    Qstring("<pre><code>", f);
    for ( blanks = 0; t ; t = t->next ) {
    if ( S(t->text) > t->dle ) {
        while ( blanks ) {
        Qchar('\n', f);
        --blanks;
        }
        code(f, T(t->text), S(t->text));
        Qchar('\n', f);
    }
    else blanks++;
    }
    Qstring("</code></pre>", f);
}
```

No option to add any class to code and pre.

If you need to add a class to format the markup, maybe you can try a workaround and generate a div with a class before the

```html
<div class="myclass">
    <pre><code>
```

Is it feasible for you?

Comment: Hey, I said exactly the same thing as a comment ! You are not answering the question

Comment: Hey @mexique1, I wanted to explain why it was not feasible with RDiscount. The moment I started creating this answer, your comment was not created, that's it. No need to yell at me, don't you think?

Comment: I'm not yelling.. actually you are right, the first part answers the question. Trying to remove my downvote..